# Cakephp upgrade php version showing error

Tags: php, cakephp, xampp

I’ve just upgraded my servers to PHP 5.4 and got this error when loading a project, which is working fine in old version

```
Declaration of JsHelper::link() should be compatible with AppHelper::link($title, $url = NULL, $options = Array, $confirmMessage = false) [CORE\Cake\View\Helper\JsHelper.php, line 434]
```

i am using xampp in window

please tell me how can i solve it

Comment: What version of CakePHP are you using?

Comment: i am using cakephp 2.0 in my old project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Read the error message

> Declaration of JsHelper::link() should be compatible with AppHelper::link($title, $url = NULL, $options = Array, $confirmMessage = false) [CORE\Cake\View\Helper\JsHelper.php, line 434]

Then look at [the method signature for that method in the core](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.8/lib/Cake/View/Helper/JsHelper.php#L293):

```
// JsHelper
link($title, $url = null, $options = array())
```

Then look at the method signature in the warning:

```
//AppHelper
link($title, $url = NULL, $options = Array, $confirmMessage = false)
```

Then read the warning again, it's saying they don't match.

### Solution

Change the AppHelper, a class in your application, to have the same method signature:

```
//AppHelper
link($title, $url = NULL, $options = Array)
```

And adjust any logic it contains accordingly.

Comment: Thanks dear friend i just find the same solution but thanks as u guide